# How to query for multiple results in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

If I want to find documents for more than one query parameter(sorry if not using correct wording), how do I do this?
i am using the c# driver.

Example
I want to find documents for both provider1 and provider2
I can do it for one i.e. 
`collection.Find(Query.EQ("ProviderId", providerId))`

In TSQL:

```
Select * From ProviderTable
Where ProviderId In (1,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for this:

```
var ids = new List<int> {1, 2};

var results = collection.Find(Query.In("ProviderId", new BsonArray(ids)));
```

Comment: Where does the class Query come from?